# Showing specific value from XML Array through foreach

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

foreach($xml->Game as $d) {

foreach( $d->SportsBook as $sb) {

foreach( $sb->Odds as $odds) {
  //   echo $odds['LineType'].' '.$odds['LastUpdated']."<br/>";

}
} 
}
```

demo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GameOdds SportsCode="MLB">
<Game Code="121" Date="08/25/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"     
Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="951" Road="Road" Note=""> <SportsBook ID="5"     
Name="5Dimes">
<Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
</SportsBook>
<SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
<Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
</SportsBook> </Game>
<Game Code="122" Date="07/02/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11" 
Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="931" Road="Road" Note="">
<SportsBook ID="2" Name="5Dimes">
<Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
</SportsBook>
<SportsBook ID="6" Name="3Dimes">
<Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="30"  />
</SportsBook> 
</Game>
<Game Code="121" Date="08/25/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"     
Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="951" Road="Road" Note=""> <SportsBook ID="5"     
Name="5Dimes">
<Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
</SportsBook>
<SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
<Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="30"  />
</SportsBook> </Game>
<Game Code="121" Date="08/31/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"     
Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="951" Road="Road" Note=""> <SportsBook ID="5"     
Name="5Dimes">
<Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
</SportsBook>
<SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
<Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
</SportsBook> </Game>
<Game Code="121" Date="08/25/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"     
Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="951" Road="Road" Note=""> <SportsBook ID="5"     
Name="5Dimes">
<Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
</SportsBook>
<SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
<Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
</SportsBook> </Game>
</GameOdds>
```

Updated my question now i want to fetch only if GAME Date="08/25/2017" Plus only fetch 2 games only.
how can i show specific Odds value into each Game. Something like 3Dimes values only. Game value and only 3dimes values from each Game .
Result will be like this

> Time:1:45 PM 
>   LineType:3 
>   LastUpdated:20
>
> Time:1:45 PM 
>   LineType:3 
>   LastUpdated:20

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using [SimpleXMLElement::xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) function:

```
$xml_data = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

foreach ($xml_data->Game as $game) {
    $t = $game['Time'];
    $odds = $game->xpath('SportsBook[@Name="3Dimes"]/Odds');
    echo 'Time: ' . $t . ' LineType: ' . $odds[0]->attributes()['LineType']
          . ' LastUpdated: ' . $odds[0]->attributes()['LastUpdated'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
Time: 1:45 PM LineType: 3 LastUpdated: 20
Time: 1:45 PM LineType: 3 LastUpdated: 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now i want to  fetch value if Date="08/25/2017" @romanperekhrest

Comment: @Asher, you could initiate a new question for the new issue

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to navigate the layers of the XML you can use XPath to find the parts your interested in...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('t1.xml');

$xpath = $xml->xpath('//SportsBook[@Name="3Dimes"]/Odds');

foreach ($xpath as $odds)   {
    echo 'Time:'.(string)$odds->xpath('parent::*/parent::*/@Time')[0]
            .' LineType:'. $odds["LineType"]
            .' LastUpdated:'.$odds["LastUpdated"]."\n";
}
```

The hardest thing with this way is that once you've gone down to the 'Odds' elements, you have to then go back up (using `parent::*`) to fetch the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://iconoun.com/demo/temp_asher.php

```html
<?php // demo/temp_asher.php
/**
 * Dealing with XML document
 *
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083520/showing-specific-value-from-xml-array-through-foreach
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';

// TEST DATA FROM THE POST AT STACK
$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GameOdds SportsCode="MLB">
  <Game Code="121" Date="07/06/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"
    Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="951" Road="Road" Note="">
    <SportsBook ID="5" Name="5Dimes">
        <Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
    </SportsBook>
    <SportsBook ID="5" Name="3Dimes">
      <Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="20"  />
    </SportsBook>
  </Game>
  <Game Code="122" Date="07/02/2017" Time="1:45 PM" HomeBoardNumber="11"
    Home="home" RoadBoardNumber="931" Road="Road" Note="">
    <SportsBook ID="2" Name="5Dimes">
      <Odds LineType="2"  LastUpdated="10"  />
    </SportsBook>
    <SportsBook ID="6" Name="3Dimes">
      <Odds LineType="3"  LastUpdated="30"  />
    </SportsBook>
  </Game>
</GameOdds>
EOD;

// MAKE AN OBJECT
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// ACTIVATE THIS TO VISUALIZE THE OBJECT
// var_dump($obj);

// EXTRACT DATA FROM THE OBJECT
foreach ($obj->Game as $g)
{
    $t = (string)$g->attributes()->Time;
    foreach ($g->SportsBook as $s)
    {
        // SKIP ANYTHING THAT IS NOT THE "Name" WE WANT
        $n = (string)$s->attributes()->Name;
        if ($n != '3Dimes') continue;

        $o = $s->Odds;
        $olt = (string)$o->attributes()->LineType;
        $olu = (string)$o->attributes()->LastUpdated;

        // SHOW THE INFORMATION FROM THE OBJECT
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo "Time:$t ";
        echo "LineType:$olt ";
        echo "LastUpdated:$olu ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath expressions allow you to fetch parts of an DOM using paths and conditions. In your case you want to output the `Odds` in `SportsBook` elements with an specific attribute. This is fairly straightforward in Xpath.

- fetch any `SportsBook` element node
  `//SportsBook`
- with a specific `Name` attribute value
  `//SportsBook[@Name="3Dimes"]`
- fetch the `Odds` child nodes of them
  `//SportsBook[@Name="3Dimes"]/Odds`

This will return an DOMNodelist (if you're using DOM) or an array (if your're using SimpleXML). The `Time` attribute is not on the `Odds` node but an ancestor node. So we use that axis.

- fetch the `Game` ancestor nodes
  `//ancestor::Game`
- their `Time` attributes
  `ancestor::Game/@Time`
- case the first (nearest) into a string
  `string(ancestor::Game/@Time)`

The last step (casting into string) only works with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. So here is a complete DOM example (The other answers show the SimpleXML logic already).

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '//SportsBook[@Name="3Dimes"]/Odds';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $odds) {
  printf(
    "Time:%s LineType:%d LastUpdated:%d\n",
    $xpath->evaluate('string(ancestor::Game/@Time)', $odds),
    $odds->getAttribute('LineType'),
    $odds->getAttribute('LastUpdated')
  );
}
```

Output:

```
Time:1:45 PM LineType:3 LastUpdated:20
Time:1:45 PM LineType:3 LastUpdated:30
```